# Reverse rysnc with multiple sources

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm working on some backup script right now. To speed the process up I used `rsync` with all folders to be backed up. *(Something like this: `rysnc -a --delete --progress $folder1 $folder2 $folder3 backupfolder/`)*

If I now want to reverse this *(meaning distributing the content of `backupfolder` to their respective folders.)* how would I do this?

**EDIT:**

I did some research and found that:

```
for folder in $folder1 $folder2 $folder3
do
    rsync -a --delete --progress backupfolder/$(basename $folder)/ $folder/
done
```

While the reverse is:

```
rysnc -a --delete --progress $folder1 $folder2 $folder3 backupfolder/
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop? It would be best if it was only one command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `backupfolder` contains only the directories you want to restore, then restore `backupfolder` itself.

```
rsync -a /path/to/backupfolder/ .
```

Note the `/` at the end of the first argument, otherwise the directories will be restored as subdirectories.

To only include certain subdirectories, use a filter.

```
rsync -a --include='/folder1' --include='/folder2' --exclude='/*' /path/to/backupfolder/ .
```

Comment: Assuming some of the folders are on different locations, and the paths are stored in variables. I know I would have to use `mv` but how would I do this? (I'll update the question too)

Comment: @BrainStone I don't understand your comment or your edit. What do you mean by “some of the folders are on different locations”? Which paths are you talking about? Why do you want to move files rather than copy them?

Comment: I made another edit to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a loop ...

```
for folder in folder1 folder2 folder3
do
   rsync -a --delete --progress backupfolder $folder
done
```

Comment: Not quite working but the idea is good.